# How to click on 'Leave Page' button in the confirmation popup?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

When I try to close the browser window, I was displayed with a popup saying "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave-data you have entered may not be saved." with two buttons "Leave page" and "Stay on Page". I want to click on 'Leave Page'.Please let me know how can I do that. I got an answer, but it is closing the popup.

```
(( JavascriptExecutor ) webDriver).executeScript( "window.close()" );
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: have you try with driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); ,.... it works sometimes

Comment: working for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Below:-

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

It will handle browser operation like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a method to call all the time that deals with the alert if it is there and does nothing otherwise:

```
void handleUnexpectedAlert() {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException ignore) {
        // This is the way to know it wasn't there
    }
}
```